# Reconciling @@TRANCOUNT

Tags: sql-server

Running SS2005.  I have a script that calls `procedureA` which in turn calls `procedureB`.

`procedureA` has no explicit transactions.  `procedureB` is split up into several small blocks of non-nested BEGIN and COMMIT TRANSACTION.

I have peppered `procedureB` with PRINT statements to show me the value of `@@TRANCOUNT`.  It's always at 0 or 1.

But when I check `master..sysprocesses` it shows open_tran at 1 or 2.  Where this extra transaction is coming from?

I am posting the 2 procedures below.  `pr_Get12Relatives` has been stripped of most of its content for clarity as it contains 1600 lines!  It just repeats the same behavior as it searches for different types of relationships.

procedureA = [pr_GetRelatives](https://sites.google.com/site/facesmapicons/pr_GetRelatives.sql?attredirects=0&d=1)

procedureB = [pr_Get12Relatives](https://sites.google.com/site/facesmapicons/pr_Get12Relatives.sql?attredirects=0&d=1)

Comment: Can you post your test code, if possible?  It'd be easier to understand what you're doing, and then in turn explain what is happening if we can all reference the same test/sample code.

Comment: Code posted above.

Comment: Is `IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS` turned on in the query options?

Comment: 'IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS' is NOT turned on.

Answer (score 1):

[This thread answers my question.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jenss/usage-of-trancount-in-dml-statements).

When a DML statement is currently being executed in a session the `open_tran` and `@@trancount` is always at least `2`.

For example

#### Connection 1

```
CREATE TABLE T( X INT PRIMARY KEY)

GO

BEGIN TRAN

INSERT INTO T VALUES(1)

WAITFOR DELAY '00:01'

ROLLBACK
```

#### Connection 2

```
INSERT INTO T VALUES(1) /*Blocks on Connection 1*/
```

#### Connection 3

(look at blocked connection 2)

```
SELECT lastwaittype,
       open_tran
FROM   master..sysprocesses
WHERE  spid = <spid of connection 2>
```

Results

```
+----------------------------------+-----------+
|           lastwaittype           | open_tran |
+----------------------------------+-----------+
| LCK_M_X                          |         2 |
+----------------------------------+-----------+
```